# C library freeing a pointer coming from Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

I want to do Rust bindings to a C library which requires a callback, and this callback must return a C-style `char*` pointer to the C library which will then free it.
The callback must be in some sense exposed to the user of my library (probably using closures), and I want to provide a Rust interface as convenient as possible (meaning accepting a `String` output if possible).

However, the C library complains when trying to `free()` a pointer coming from memory allocated by Rust, probably because Rust uses jemalloc and the C library uses malloc.

So currently I can see two workarounds using `libc::malloc()`, but both of them have disadvantages:

- Give the user of the library a slice that he must fill (inconvenient, and imposes length restrictions)
- Take his `String` output, copy it to an array allocated by malloc, and then free the `String` (useless copy and allocation)

Can anybody see a better solution?

Here is an equivalent of the interface of the C library, and the implementation of the ideal case (if the C library could free a String allocated in Rust)

```
extern crate libc;
use std::ffi::CString;
use libc::*;
use std::mem;

extern "C" {
    // The second parameter of this function gets passed as an argument of my callback
    fn need_callback(callback: extern fn(arbitrary_data: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_char,
                     arbitrary_data: *mut c_void);
}

// This function must return a C-style char[] that will be freed by the C library
extern fn my_callback(arbitrary_data: *mut c_void) -> *mut c_char {
    unsafe {
        let mut user_callback: *mut &'static mut FnMut() -> String = mem::transmute(arbitrary_data); //'
        let user_string = (*user_callback)();
        let c_string = CString::new(user_string).unwrap();
        let ret: *mut c_char = mem::transmute(c_string.as_ptr());
        mem::forget(c_string); // To prevent deallocation by Rust
        ret
    }
}

pub fn call_callback(mut user_callback: &mut FnMut() -> String) {
    unsafe {
        need_callback(my_callback, mem::transmute(&mut user_callback));
    }
}
```

The C part would be equivalent to this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef char* (*callback)(void *arbitrary_data);
void need_callback(callback cb, void *arbitrary_data) {
    char *user_return = cb(arbitrary_data);
    free(user_return); // Complains as the pointer has been allocated with jemalloc
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might require some annoying work on your part, but what about exposing a type that implements [`Write`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html), but is backed by memory allocated via `malloc`? Then, your client can use the `write!` macro (and friends) instead of allocating a `String`.

Here's how it currently works with `Vec`:

```
let mut v = Vec::new();
write!(&mut v, "hello, world");
```

You would "just" need to implement the two methods and then you would have a stream-like interface.

Comment: Oh I didn't think about that, thanks! Though if I am correct malloc has a pretty dumb realloc function, that just does a malloc / copy / free whereas jemalloc can realloc in place. So a growable type implemented in malloc could imply several copies during reallocations, which means that it might be both more convenient and faster to use a classic String, and then do a single malloc / copy. I guess I will need to do some tests!

Comment: Or you might use a rope and malloc later. Crates.io have a couple ropes.

Comment: @ArtemGr wouldn't a rope involve allocations on the Rust side, thus requiring a second allocation via malloc later?

Comment: @Vaelden I don't think that `realloc` has a "dumb" implementation, and it's probably hard to globally characterize `realloc` - it wouldn't surprise me if every platform has different implementations, and you can always do some linker trickery to replace `malloc` and friends with a custom library at runtime. I agree that profiling is the right solution if you are that worried about performance though!

Comment: @Shepmaster Sure. It's the most efficient way to build a string, though, since it avoids the copying during the realloc. There is a curious comment here - https://github.com/servo/servo/wiki/Workweek-encoding - "*kmc: Does SM use ropes? zwarich: Everyone does.*"  ; )
Not to mention that it's more memory-efficient that way, avoiding any prolonged use of the extra memory at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Forgot to mention that to simply build a string a deque might be even better than a rope. But then it's more low-level implementing string building over a deque, a rope already has the right methods. Come to think of it, a large string might be build over an mmap memory, though it becames a trade-off choosing a large-enough memory size unless there's "huge pages" or something. The mmap address might then be passed to C as is.