# The best way in Rust to return a dynamic string from extern "C" method to be consumed by C or C++

Tags: c++, c, rust

*This one is somewhat relevant, but the answer is not really clear for me:
[C library freeing a pointer coming from Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866103/c-library-freeing-a-pointer-coming-from-rust)*

There's also an [example with static string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ffi.html#calling-rust-code-from-c) in the book, however it would not properly work with the dynamically created string.

I came to this solution finally where calling C/C++ code allocates and later deallocates memory for the string to be received, but it looks somewhat ugly and has to define some particular length for unknown string:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn rs_string_in_string_out(s_raw: *const c_char, out: *mut c_char) -> c_int {
    // take string from the input C string
    if s_raw.is_null() { return 0; }

    let c_str: &CStr = unsafe { CStr::from_ptr(s_raw) };
    let buf: &[u8] = c_str.to_bytes();
    let str_slice: &str = std::str::from_utf8(buf).unwrap();
    let str_buf: String = str_slice.to_owned();

    //produce a new string
    let result = String::from(str_buf + " append from Rust");
    let len = result.len();

    //create C string for output
    let c_result = CString::new(result);

    //write string into out pointer passed by C++ addon
    unsafe{ std::ptr::copy(c_result.unwrap().as_ptr(), out, len); };

    // return result length
    return len as c_int;
}
```

It would be nice to have somewhat that actually returns a value, rather than writing into mutable argument.

Comment: *It would be nice to have somewhat that actually returns a value* => you can always create a C struct that holds both a `char*` and a `size_t` and use that as the return type; it's hardly Rust's fault here if C does not have a all-in-one result and you have to write it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, Matthieu! There's EOF symbol in the end of C "string" which is sufficient. The question was more about deallocating the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is a brand new, but documentation states (https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/custom-allocators.html#default-allocator), that libraries use alloc_system by default, which means that we're free to use free in C/C++. It is also possible to add #![feature(alloc_system)] to the header to feel safer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`into_raw`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.into_raw) on a `CString` to turn it into a raw pointer, which you can then return from your function.

You shouldn't rely on Rust using the system allocator. There's no guarantee that your Rust code will link to the same `free` as the C/C++ code. On Windows, for example, there's `msvcrt`, `msvcr80`, `msvcr90`, etc., and they all manage separate heaps. Therefore, your library should still provide a function to free memory that it allocates. For `CString`, you should use [`CString::from_raw`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.from_raw) for this (you don't need to use the result, Rust will automatically drop it, which will free the string on the heap).